# JAX-B / JSON: inheritance, composite-pattern, unmarshal exception

Tags: json, inheritance, jaxb, jersey, unmarshalling

i'm working on a RESTful WebService (NetBeans + Jersey) and trying to realize a UI-Description (Label, Buttons,...) for mobile Apps (Android).

I used the Composite-Design-Pattern to create a UIContainer, UIBasicElements, UIComplexElements, and so on...

My Problem is:
The UIContainer contains a
`private List<UIComponent> uiComponents;`.

If i add

```
@XmlSeeAlso( { 
    UIBasicLabel.class, 
    UIBasicIcon.class, 
    UIBasicButton.class,
    ... 
} )
```

to the class `public abstract class UIComponent` i get the JSON-Format i want, i.e. something like

```
{ ..., uiComponents : [ {Label} , {Icon} , ... ] , ... }
```

which i can process on my Android-Client.
I also noticed, that a `@type : ClassName` property is added to the JSON-Output.
Isn't this added to give the unmarshaller a hint, what class to use?

With the Jersey-Client i get an Exception on unmarshalling:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXParseException2; lineNumber: 0; columnNumber: 0; Unable to create an instance of de.materna.mobile.management.entities.uidescription.UIComponent]
```

As far as i understand, i need to modify the UIContainer.class to

```
@XmlElementRef
private List<UIComponent> uiComponents;
```

so the unmarshaller knows what to deserialize here.

However, my Problem is, with `@XmlElementRef` the JSON becomes this:

```
{ ..., Label : [ ... ] , Icon : [ ... ], ... }
```

instead of

```
{ ..., uiComponents : [ {Label} , {Icon} , ... ] , ... }
```

Is there any way to accomplish both?

Thank you very much!

P.S: sorry for my bad english - i hope it's not too hard to read/understand

Answer (score 0):

Start with XML schema which describes your object model, then run xjc or wsimport (tools from JDK) which would generate you your Java classes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, after a little research i decided to go with the Jackson JSON library. It seems to fit my needs better, and it was very easy to integrate to my project.